# Duplicate items in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a plot with stacked columns and two lines in ggplot2. However, the legend items of the lines also show in the legend of the columns. Any one knows how to remove them from the column legend?

Code below:

```
##Remove Objects
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
##Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)
##Data
set.seed(12345)
d.fig6.1 <- data.frame(mm=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun",
"Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),a.1=(rnorm(12)*5)^2)
d.fig6.1$a.2 <- (rnorm(12)*5)^2
d.fig6.1$a.3 <- (rnorm(12)*5)^2
d.fig6.1$a.4 <- (rnorm(12)*5)^2
d.fig6.1$a.5 <- (rnorm(12)*5)^2
d.fig6.1$a.6 <- (rnorm(12)*5)^2
d.fig6.1$a.7 <- (rnorm(12)*5)^2
d.fig6.2 <- data.frame(mm=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun",
"Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),a.8=(rnorm(12)*5)^2)
d.fig6.2$a.9 <- (rnorm(12)*5)^2
d.fig6.1 <- melt(d.fig6.1,id="mm")
d.fig6.2 <- melt(d.fig6.2,id="mm")
d.fig6.1
d.fig6.2
##Plot
theme_set(theme_bw(7)) #25
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", 
"#D55E00", "#CC79A7","red")
sp.6 <- ggplot(d.fig6.1, aes(x=mm, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_col() 
+ labs(x="") + labs(y="[Units]") 
+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
+ scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette,name="") 
+ geom_text(data=d.fig6.1, aes(label = round(value,digits=2)), position = position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=2) 
+ theme(legend.title = element_blank()) 
+ geom_line(data=d.fig6.2, aes(x=as.numeric(mm), y=value, color=variable),size=1,inherit.aes = FALSE) 
+ geom_text(data=d.fig6.2, aes(label=round(value,digits=2)),hjust=0, vjust=0, size=2.5)
sp.6
```

[image: sp.6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `fill = variable` out of the top level `ggplot(aes(...))` mapping. Keep only the aesthetic mappings common to all geoms there. This way you don't really need `inherit.aes = FALSE`, either:

```
ggplot(d.fig6.1,
       aes(x = mm, y = value, label = round(value, digits = 2))) +

  geom_col(aes(fill = variable)) +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2) +

  geom_line(data = d.fig6.2,
            aes(color = variable, group = variable),
            size = 1) +
  geom_text(data = d.fig6.2, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 0, size = 2.5) +

  labs(x = "", y = "[Units]") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette, name="") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image: plot]

**Explanation**: By including `fill = variable` in the top level aesthetic mapping, every geom that doesn't have `inherit.aes = FALSE` set explicitly will inherit this as part of the aesthetic mapping for its level.

In this case, `geom_line` & the second `geom_text` both use a different data source (d.fig6.2 instead of d.fig6.1), but `geom_text` still inherits `fill = variable` from the top level mapping. So the variable values from d.fig6.2 ("a.8" & "a.9") are added to the fill palette, even though they aren't used anywhere.

I stripped down your code for a more minimal example that reproduces the problem below:

```
# this will result in a.8 & a.9 in the column legend
# because geom_text inherits aes(fill = variable) from ggplot()
ggplot(d.fig6.1,
       aes(x = mm, y = value, fill = variable,
           label = round(value, digits = 2))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(data = d.fig6.2)

# this will not
# because aes(fill = variable) is moved from ggplot() to geom_col()
ggplot(d.fig6.1,
       aes(x = mm, y = value,
           label = round(value, digits = 2))) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable)) +
  geom_text(data = d.fig6.2)

# this will not, either
# because geom_text() includes all the aes mappings it requires, & inherit.aes = FALSE
ggplot(d.fig6.1,
       aes(x = mm, y = value, fill = variable,
           label = round(value, digits = 2))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(data = d.fig6.2, 
            aes(x = mm, y = value, 
                label = round(value, digits = 2)),
            inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestions solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `+ guides(color = FALSE)` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried and the result is that the stacked columns legend remains the same and the lines legend disappears. Furthermore, the colors for a.8 and a.9 do not correspond to the lines. I would rather have the lines legend and remove a.8 and a.9 from the columns legend.